# UPDATE Query from a SELECT Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I know this is probably simple and I'm just missing something but I can't seem to figure this out.

I can't get the variable in the UPDATE statement.  If I put in the user_id it works so somehow I'm not passing the variable off.

```
$query = "SELECT accounts.username, email_activate.email, accounts.user_id FROM accounts INNER JOIN email_activate ON accounts.user_id = email_activate.user_id WHERE dt_welcome = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND dt_start <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$message =  "Hello <b>".$row['username']."</b>, <br/><br/>";

$to = "".$row['email']."";

$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE email_activate SET dt_welcome = NOW() WHERE user_id = ".$row['user_id']." ");

[other mail stuff .....]

}
```

Again, I know it's probably something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use `var_dump($row);`? what does it gives you? Also look into PDO approach to db connections. `mysql_` is being deprecated.

Comment: What do the user ids look like?

Comment: @Gordon just 5 charachters  '8RRTX'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two queries and a loop, when you can do this all in one query?

```
UPDATE email_active ea JOIN
       accounta a
       ON a.user_id = ea.user_id
    SET dt_welcome = NOW()
WHERE dt_welcome = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
      dt_start <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

EDIT:

The problem with your query is that you need single quotes around the user id:

```
UPDATE email_activate
    SET dt_welcome = NOW()
    WHERE user_id = '".$row['user_id']."' "
```

Of course, you should be using mysqli_ or PDO and have parameterized queries.  The latter would have prevented you from having this problem in the first place.

Comment: @Zentoaku . . . s/he can fetch the updated records or perhaps do the work in the database.

Comment: @Gordon I have to send an email to everyone that comes up in that select statement, that's why I'm using the loop.  Everything works except I can't get the  ".$row['user_id']."  value to populate.

Comment: Thanks.  Going to look up PDO now.